# How do I configure xcat to not use weak ciphers?

Tags: ssl

My vulnerability scanner is taking issue with the SSL config in the xcatd service running on port 3001. The scanner is able to make the following connections:

```
Medium Strength Ciphers (>= 56-bit and < 112-bit key)

SSLv3 DES-CBC-SHA Kx=RSA Au=RSA Enc=DES(56) Mac=SHA1
TLSv1 DES-CBC-SHA Kx=RSA Au=RSA Enc=DES(56) Mac=SHA1

The fields above are : {OpenSSL ciphername} Kx={key exchange} Au={authentication} Enc={symmetric encryption method} Mac={message authentication code} {export flag}
```

This is a reference good configuration for a popular web server, but I'm not sure how to translate it to xcat:

```
SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
```

Comment: Looks like /opt/xcat/sbin/xcatd is a huge Perl script that uses IO::Socket::SSL

Answer (score 0):

The xcat configuration setting xcatsslciphers corresponds to the [IO::Socket::SSL](http://search.cpan.org/~sullr/IO-Socket-SSL-1.955/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm) configuration setting SSL_Cipher_list, which takes the exact same input as the SSLCipherSuite directive in Apache.

```
sudo sqlite3 /etc/xcat/site.sqlite

insert into site (key, value) VALUES ('xcatsslciphers', 'ALL:!ADH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM');
```

You can then verify config value as follows:

```
select * from site order by key;
.exit
```

Restart xcat:

```
sudo service xcatd restart
```

Verify security:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:3001 -cipher DES-CBC-SHA -tls1
```

You should not see a certificate come up.